# internal ext of module spectra

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra

I have several possibly elementary and closely related questions about $\text{Hom}$ and $\text{Ext}$ functors in category theory. I think the questions  are similar enough to live in a single post. I apologize if they are too open-ended, but I am not knowledgeable enough of the subject to be more precise.

1. For an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$ with objects $A$ and $B$, one can define an abelian group $\text{Ext}^1_\mathcal{C}(A,B)$ of equivalence classes of extensions of $A$ by $B$. When is $\text{Ext}$ a derived functor of $\text{Hom}$?
2. A *closed category* is defined by the notion of an internal $\text{hom}$ functor$$\text{hom}(-,-):\mathcal{C}^\text{op}\times\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$$related to the familiar external $\text{Hom}$ by composing with a forgetful functor. When (if ever) is there a useful notion of *internal* $\text{ext}$? What is it? And how is $\text{ext}$ related to $\text{hom}$?
3. For a fixed commutative ring spectrum $E$, one can define the category of $E$-module spectra. I believe this category is closed and abelian. Do questions (1) and (2) have nice answers here?

Comment: 1. If you have enough projectives or injectives, then the usual proof goes through. 2. You could define internal Ext as the appropriate derived functor.

Comment: 1. Yes, if I have enough injectives, I can construct a derived functor of Hom and call it Ext, but does this always coincide with the Ext I defined above?

Comment: 2. I guess it makes sense to work with $\text{ext}$, the derived functor of $\text{hom}$, assuming enough injectives. What if there aren't? Can the set of extensions be given the structure of a spectrum, for example?

Comment: 3. In the construction of the derived functor $\text{ext}$, taking the homology of a sequence of spectra isn't very intuitive for me. Is there a more concrete topological notion of $\text{ext}^1(E,F)$ for spectra $E$ and $F$?

Comment: There is a proof that the Yoneda Ext is a derived functor. It assumes the existence of enough projectives. Dualise that. The meaning of internal Ext is less clear. I don't know much about spectra.

Comment: OK, thank you @ZhenLin.

Comment: I don't think the category of $E$-module spectra is abelian. It's homotopy category is triangulated though. One can then define derived functors with respect to a given homological ideal.